# Swiftui animate on struct bool change

Tags: swift, swiftui

I Have a struct called line, which contains a bool called isDone.

```
struct Line : Hashable {
   var isDone : Bool = false
   var text : String 
}
```

My viewmodel contains an array of these, once a line is entered the isDone is set to true.

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var lines : [Line] = []
    @Published var currentRowIndex : Int = 0

func EnterWord() {
    lines[currentRowIndex].isDone = true   
    currentRowIndex += 1
}

}
```

When the line is entered I would like to have a 3D animation as seen below.

```
struct Line : View{
    var line : Line
    
var body: some View {
                Text(line.tex)
                    .rotation3DEffect(
                        Angle.degrees(line.isDone ? 180: 0),
                    axis: (1,0,0),
                    perspective: 0)
                 .animation(.linear(duration: 4.0), value: 180)
            }     
    }

struct MainView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel : ViewModel = ViewModel()
    var body: some View {

        VStack(spacing:0){
            ForEach(viewModel.lines, id: \.self){ line in
                Line(line: line)
            }
            
            Button(action: {
                viewModel.Enter()
            })
            {
                Text("Add")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The rotation is shown but not animated, does the lack of animation have something to do with me using a struct instead of an ObservableObject? or is the animation code itself wrong?

Comment: try to set animation line like this : ```.animation(.linear(duration: 4.0), value: line.isDone ? 180: 0)```

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't seem to help

Comment: Could you please add the whole code ?

Comment: added more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the `ForEach` View struct with `id:\.self` when using value types, you have to either supply the name of the identifier property or make your data conform to `Identifiable` that has an `id` property. e.g.

```
struct Line : Identifiable {
   let id = UUID()
   var isDone = false
   var text: String 
}

ForEach(model.lines) { line in
```

This is because the `ForEach` needs to know the identifier to track changes, because with value types they are copied around and there is no reference to track.

Also you shouldn't init your model lifetime manager object with `@ObservableObject` because it creates a new object every time the View is init which is on every state change of the parent. You can use `@StateObject` instead if you want the object to be destroyed when this View dissapears. If you want it for the lifetime of your app you can init it as a singleton or global and then use `@ObservedObject var = Model.shared`.

Comment: i see what you mean that the init for the line view is being called everytime the line isDone value changes, I added the Identifiable but the Init for the view is still being called, how do I fix this?

Comment: the View's init is always called but body is only called when the properties have changed, its your responsibility to make the Views as small as possible so body is only called when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

remove perspective and try like this .rotation3DEffect(.degrees(line.isDone ? 180: 0), axis: (x: 1, y: 0, z: 0))

Comment: use single tilde symbol to give format to single line of code.
For example: `print("");`  
The code is between two tildes.